# Clarification about closed question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I would like to understand the reception of my first question here: [Monitor misbehaving with stock power supply](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/74434/47751)

It's closed as *unclear*, but I assume that this is not the real reason. If it should be closed, I assume *off topic* would be better since it turned out to be what seems like a general HDMI problem, and not something specific to Raspberry PI.

But not knowing that, what was the real problem with the question? I thought is was obviously about Raspberry PI hardware issues, and that it as such was on topic here.

Comment: I don't think it should have been closed. There was some more info you could have included, but I don't think it was so bad a down or close vote was warranted.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for taking the time to seek clarification about something affecting you on the main site. It's nice to see some different people make use of the Meta site.

Your question was most likely closed as unclear as there is limited information about your problem in the question. You didn't make it explicit what wasn't working or what you had tried and the results obtained from trying different solutions.

For example you were facing a problem with the monitor, which could have been caused by the Pi. However, in your question you did not specify if you had got the monitor to work with a different device, or if the Pi worked with a different monitor.

When trying to solve a technical issue like the one you experienced, before seeking advice online its really important you go through some sort of troubleshooting process. Having a go at isolating the problem is the first step to take. That way if you then can't figure out what the problem is after that, at least when you ask other people for help they have some sort of starting point for solving the problem.

You can of course go back and edit your question to include relevant detail to the problem and request the question be re-opened. I suggest re-formatting the question so it follows some kind of logical sequence. The reason the question has so many comments on it is because people were trying to figure out exactly what the problem was.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with your reasoning as to why it was put on hold as "unclear" and how the question could be improved by providing additional details.

Comment: PS: I hope this is part of your campaign to become an elected moderator, Lord Vader! You have been pretty active in the review queues and various other tasks to keep the site running smoothly, so I would really like to encourage you to nominate yourself again.

Comment: It's something I'm currently considering. I just need to think carefully how I would fit a moderator role on the site around a very busy university life! I am however honoured that you think I should go for the position.